# Looking for download of previous version (v1.3.1) of Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I recently got added to a project team which is using the following version of Mule Studio:

> Version 1.3.1 Build 201209041237

I would like to download and install this version on my Mac but I cannot find the download location anywhere. Can someone tell me where I can find it? 
I can of course download 3.4 but that only works with Mule ESB 3.4 and we cannot upgrade all our Mule instances just because a new developer is added to the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Studio allows you to download alternate ESB runtimes from an update site.

I see 3.3.3 EE as an option: would this work for you or are you using an older version of Mule (3.2 or before)?

Comment: We are using the Mule 3.3.1 CE version unfortunately. Or can I update the 'Available Software Sites' in Mule Studio so I can obtain an older version?

Comment: 3.3.3 EE should be OK: it's built on 3.3.3 CE. Just don't use any EE feature and you should be good.

Answer (score 10):

if you go to 
http://mule-studio-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/

you should see a listing of all the files available.

copy the key of the one you want to use and append it to the above link you should be able to download

1.3.1-01-GA-CE/MuleStudio-CE-for-linux-32bit-1.3.1-201209061215.tar.gz

eg. 
http://mule-studio-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/1.3.1-01-GA-CE/MuleStudio-CE-for-linux-32bit-1.3.1-201209061215.tar.gz